# How to: Load hdpi resource into mdpi system

Tags: android

I'm writing a custom launcher desktop that uses a 2x3 grid of icons rather than the standard 4x4 grid.  For ease of use, we also need to have the shortcut icons displayed larger than normal.  I can accomplish this by creating resized icons, but the obvious result is pixelation.  The device we're developing for is MDPI, so the original icons are 48x48 pixels.

So my question is this: if there are HDPI or XHDPI resources available for the apps in the desktop, is there any way to load those instead?  I don't see an obvious way to bypass Android's automated handling of resources.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution I used to load a hdpi drawable icon from another application (works only with Android 4.0)    :

```
PackageInfo pi = packages.get(i);

ai = new AppListAdapter.AppItem();
try {
   Context otherAppCtx =  getApplicationContext().createPackageContext(pi.applicationInfo.packageName, CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
   ai.Icon = otherAppCtx.getResources().getDrawableForDensity(pi.applicationInfo.icon,  DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH);

} catch (Exception e) {
    ai.Icon = pi.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I saw that they added getDrawableForDensity().  I thought about implementing it myself, but the bulk of the work is done in native code, which I didn't immediately have access too.  Going with a work-around for now.  Thanks though!

Comment: Worst case scenario is to continue with resized (pixelated) icons.  But we use hdpi icons (in mdpi folder) for any apps that we can create to minimize the pain.  I still hope to revisit this soon and try a few more things.  I think I can create a Resource object based on current resources, but with a modified DisplayMetrics.

Comment: since some launchers need one level of higher density of the device one, is there a way to get it automatically to this level?